# Overrides control resource with setter in style file

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have the code to override a CalendarDatePicker resource (CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground) in XAML.

```
<CalendarDatePicker Style="{StaticResource CalendarDatePickerStyle}">
    <CalendarDatePicker.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground" Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
    </CalendarDatePicker.Resources>
</CalendarDatePicker>
```

Now, I need reuse this code, creating a generic style in my styles file project, to use in the others CalendarDatePicker in my project, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarDatePickerStyle" TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">        
        <Setter ....
</Style>
```

How should I do that with a Setter?

And if I wanted to apply a generic style to all project calendars without having to be typing in every Calendar Style={StaticResource ...}, how should I define this style?

Comment: Literally just take that `SolidColorBrush` resource and throw it in your resource dictionary (keep the x:Key name the same) so it overrides as the default in the order of inheritance. No need for the style template stuff amigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly add the SolidColorBrush definition into your App.xaml resources and it will override the default styling. The main thing is to use the same Key as the control uses.

So for example to override CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground with your own color in every CalendarDatePicker, make the App.xaml look like the following:

```
<Application
x:Class="App1.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
RequestedTheme="Light">

<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground" Color="Green"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/styling-controls) about styling controls in UWP.

Comment: Ya like that... +1

Comment: I was trying to add into my style file "CalendarDatePicker.Resources" and inside, in some way, the CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground property and not directly without the "CalendarDatePicker.Resources" tag. Newbie stuffs... Thx!